# How to make sure PHP code does not depend on test classes or dev-dependencies?

Tags: php, continuous-integration, dependencies, static-analysis

I want to make sure that my production code (namespace `App\`)  does not depend on classes installed as dev-dependencies (because I don't install them in production) and not on any class in the `App\Test` namespace.

Currently I have a very crude check in my CI pipeline, where I run PHPStan and composer twice: Once for the full project (so PHPStan covers everything), then I run composer with the `--no-dev` flag and run PHPStan again on the production code. This seems wasteful to me. Are there better options for static analysis?

Comment: Running the same tools in multiple stages of deployment is normal. Most people run those tools in the test server, then in the staging server and sometimes in production. It's not wasteful, you are using resources to make sure your code works on different environments.

Comment: How do you run PHPStan if you've used `--no-dev`? Where is PHPStan coming from?

Comment: I'm running PHPStan from a custom Docker container where I have installed it as a global script. I could also download the PHAR instead.

Comment: Great question @chiborg. Today I found out places in my code that use classes that are dependencies of my require-dev dependencies. Have you found any solution?